# Nautical charts symbols in vector format

Tags: vector, charts, openstreetmap, symbols

Please help me to find nautical charts symbols, used on nautical navigation maps in vector format. I have found following PDF: http://pdept.cgaux.org/Documents/Active/NS/Charts/Chart_No_1_Full.pdf

It contains all symbols I need, but unfortunately they are all in raster.

I take a look to the OpenStreetMap & OpenSeaMap and similar OpenSource projects, but unable to solve my problem. And I feel sense that redrawing such symbols from raster PDF itself is not a good idea and looks like reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 1):

You already looked at the right places. [OpenSeaMap](http://openseamap.org/) seems to have its SVG icon repository [here](http://openseamap.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/openseamap/renderer/) (recursively browse through the subdirectories, there are multiple icon locations). Furthermore there is a [marine tagging proposal](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Proposed_features/marine-tagging) in the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) wiki also containing lots of different marine icons in SVG format (also browse through the various links there which might lead to more icons). And then there is [FreieTonne](http://www.freietonne.de/), a similar project to OpenSeaMap, for which I couldn't determine the location of their icon set.

In all cases keep the licenses for the specific icon sets in mind.

Comment: OpenSeaMap publishes a rather complete SVG library: https://github.com/OpenSeaMap/josm

It is organized by symbol, see http://www.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/mcd/chart1/ChartNo1.pdf for the organization.

It also has international and NOAA designations.